# Is there a way to fetch 'Input Data' from an Ethereum Transaction using either etherscan API or eth_getlogs?

Tags: api, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiyJi.png)

the above image shows what the 'input data' section on etherscan looks like and im wondering if its possible to fetch this on etherscan API or eth_getlogs

Comment: Did u got the answer? Im stuck here?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if u can do it with etherscan API, but i don't think.

you can do it using tools like thegraph.com, you will make API for ethereum main net by yourself